# apache2 (mod_wsgi-express): Syntax error

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I accidentally deleted the virtual environment from the apache server holding my Django website. 
I created new virtual env and reinstalled everything on the server but when I try to restart the server using command:

```
sudo /etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl restart
```

I get the error:

```
apache2 (mod_wsgi-express): Syntax error on line 155 of /etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/httpd.conf: Cannot load /www/site_name/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so into server: /www/site_name/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked the **venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/** folder and there is no folder named **mod_wsgi** in it. 
Should I create the folder manually? 
I am new to server handling and am not sure weather this is right solution. (Earlier I had done a git clean -fd which deleted the virtual env from the server ending up in this situation.)

A piece of **/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/httpd.conf** looks like this: 
(line 155 being the line starting with "LoadModule.." )

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_PHP5>
<IfModule !php5_module>
Loadmodule php5_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/libphp5.so'
</IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfDefine>
</IfModule>

LoadModule wsgi_module '/www/site_name/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_METRICS>
<IfModule !status_module>
LoadModule status_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_status.so'
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you get if you run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config``. Looks like your virtual environment is now in a different location perhaps. If that is the case, you should run the ``mod_wsgi-express start-server --setup-only`` command you ran previously to create the ``/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80`` directory. The ``apachectl`` script in that directory should have a comment at the start which says what options you used last time.

Comment: I get: 'mod_wsgi-express: command not found'
I installed the virtual env is in the same location.

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment when you tried running that command? If you did, it would appear that mod_wsgi hasn't been installed.

Comment: I activated venv. After checking using dpkg commands I found: 
 apache2 (dev, bin data, utils) and **libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3** are installed. but package **libapache2-mod-wsgi**  is not installed.

Comment: After pip installing `mod_wsgi`, I did a collect static and restarted the server again. It worked. 
I did not have to run the `start-server --setup` command (Was it because the server was already running?)
Thanks you very much @GrahamDumpleton  :)

Comment: Don't know, but if using ``pip install mod_wsgi`` you don't need either ``libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`` or ``libapache2-mod-wsgi``.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful..